# associative array_search not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am trying to array_search for associative array in Php but the function isnot working as expected. can anyone help me with this. currently using php version 5.4

```
<?php 
$mainArray = array("array1","array2","array3");
    $array1 = array("item"=>"apple","price"=>2);
    $array2 = array("item"=>"banana","price"=>3);
    $array3 = array("item"=>"carrot","price"=>4);
echo phpversion();
echo "this line ".array_search("apple", array_column($mainArray,'item'));
echo "end";
?>
```

Comment: Use `print_r($mainArray);` and just look inside your array what values you have stored there.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** In your code `$mainArray = array("array1","array2","array3");` you are declaring array of strings not array of arrays.

**Change this:**

```
$mainArray = array("array1","array2","array3");
```

**This:**

```
$mainArray = array($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

And use this `$mainArray = array($array1, $array2, $array3)` after definition of `$array1`, `$array2`, `$array3`

**PHP code:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778762)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array1 = array("item" => "apple", "price" => 2);
$array2 = array("item" => "banana", "price" => 3);
$array3 = array("item" => "carrot", "price" => 4);

//should be declared like this and should be after defintion of $array1, $array2, $array3
$mainArray = array($array1, $array2, $array3);

echo "this line " . array_search("apple", array_column($mainArray, 'item'));
?>
```